# Firestore v9 - React - get a specific document by field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have a posts document, which has title, tags, imgUrl, content, order, source fields.

I want to use firestore v9 to fetch 1 element at a time in his order, but I'm not getting it.

```
const dbb = async (orderr) => {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(
      collection(db, 'posts'),
      orderBy("order"),
      startAt(orderr),
      limit(1)
    )

    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      setTitle(doc.data().title)
      setTags(doc.data().tags)
      setSource(doc.data().source)
      setImgUrl(doc.data().imgUrl)
      setContent(doc.data().content)
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    dbb(2)
  }, [])
```

It is returning document of order 1, instead of 2.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a document reference instead of just the number 2. [Docs here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/query-cursors#use_a_document_snapshot_to_define_the_query_cursor)
I think i also had problems once with getting the startAt operator working so i just started using docRefs instead. If you don't want to do that, try converting the number 2 to a string first `dbb(String(2))` but I don't know if that would help. Just thinking that maybe the document ID that its trying to start at has a type mismatch.